# Is there a way to count distinct values in mongoose with specific cut off date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

For example, I have the following two docs

```
[
   {
    "_id": "5fc534505144dd0030c44f8e",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-14T15:11:21.327Z"
    "user_id": "2",
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fc534505144dd0030c44f8e",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-14T14:10:40.427Z",
    "user_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fc534595144dd0030c44f95",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-13T14:10:58.027Z",
    "user_id": "1"
  }
]
```

the results should be

```
[
  {
    "date": "2020-12-13",
    "count":1
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-12-14",
    "count":2
  }
  ]
```

where the **count** is the number of distinct docs via user_ids till the date that specific cut off date

Answer (score 1):

given data

```
data=[
   {
    "createdAt": "2020-12-14T15:11:21.327Z",
    "user_id": "2",
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2020-12-14T14:10:40.427Z",
    "user_id": "1"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2020-12-13T14:10:58.027Z",
    "user_id": "1"
  },{
    "createdAt": new Date("2020-12-14T14:10:58.027Z"),
  }
]
> db.dummy.insert(data)
```

You may use aggregate: use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with _id being the date's day in conjunction with [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/))

```
> db.dummy.aggregate({$group:{_id:{$substr:['$createdAt', 0, 10]}, count:{$sum:1}}})
{ "_id" : "2020-12-14", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "2020-12-13", "count" : 1 }
```

---

edit: mongoose wise same may hold

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dummy')

const UDate = mongoose.model('X', { createdAt:String, user_id: String }, 'dummy')

;(async()=>{
  mongoose.set('debug', true)
  const group = {$group:{_id:{$substr:['$createdAt', 0, 10]}, count:{$sum:1}}}
  const v = await UDate.aggregate([group])
  console.log('s : ', JSON.stringify(v))
  mongoose.disconnect()
})()
```

edit2: to handle unicity of userIds so there are not counted twice per date, you may use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) instead of sum followed by a projection using [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

```
  const group = {$group:{_id:{$substr:['$createdAt', 0, 10]}, userIds:{$addToSet:'$user_id'}}}
  const count = {$project:{date:'$_id', count: {$size: '$userIds'}} }
  const v = await Stock.aggregate([group, count])
```

Lastly, if you feel always more, you can "rename" the _id field as date during the projection

```
{$project:{date:'$_id', _id:0, count: {$size: '$userIds'}} }
```

Comment: I need to count the user_id distinct number only, not sum ;), which should give a count: 2 for 14-12

Comment: I dont have time right now, in the group pipeline, you may use addToSet with user_id, instead of sum, then add another $project pipeline which takes the size of the set. Ill eventually update answer later on

Answer (score 0):

- `$gorup` by `createdAt` date after getting substring using `$substr` and make array of unique user ids on the base of `$addToset`
- get total element in `count` array using `$size`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $substr: ["$createdAt", 0, 10] },
      count: { $addToSet: "$user_id" }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { count: { $size: "$count" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8t5Auko2rVA)